# TypeError: sequence item 12: expected str instance, NoneType found

Tags: python, string, list, append, indexof

Here is my code:

```
import re
with open('newfiles.txt') as f:
    s = f.read()
uniquelist = []
error = re.findall(r"[\w]+|[^\s\w]", (s))
for word in error:
    if word not in uniquelist:
        uniquelist.append(word)
print ("Here are the words in their first appearing index form: ")
my_indexes = ' '.join(str(uniquelist.index(word)+1) for word in error)
print (my_indexes)
file = open("newfiletwo.txt","w")
file.write (' '.join(str(my_indexes)))
file.close()
file = open("newfilethree.txt","w")
file.write(' '.join(uniquelist))
file.close()
word_base = None
with open('newfilethree.txt', 'rt') as f_base:
    word_base = [None] + [z.strip() for z in f_base.read().split()]
sentence_seq = None
with open('newfiletwo.txt', 'rt') as f_select:
   sentence_seq = [word_base[int(i)] for i in f_select.read().split()]
print(my_indexes)
print(' '.join(sentence_seq))
```

It takes a text file and returns the positions(indexes) of the words and punctuations within it. If something repeats, the first encountered position index is given. So it, prints out the indexes. Secondly after saving the separated individual words as a file and the list of indexes, I am trying to recreate the text using them. So the final output should be the original sentence with punctuation itself. But unfortunately, when the program runs through the last line of code i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "E:\Python\Final.py", line 26, in <module>
        print(' '.join(sentence_seq))
TypeError: sequence item 12: expected str instance, NoneType found
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Well, `sentence_seq[12]` is `None`...

Comment: @thebjorn What do you mean?, I'm quite new to python as a whole

Comment: `word_base[0]` is `None`. So if any of the elements of `f_select.read().split()` are `0`, you'll put `None` into that element of `sentence_seq`. But `join()` expects all the list elements to be strings.

Comment: The error message is telling you that while executing `print(' '.join(sentence_seq))` a type error occurred because at "sequence item 12" (ie. `sentence_seq[12]`), when needing a string there was a `None` value instead.  Pythons `' '.join(lst)` requires all elements of `lst` to be of type string.

Comment: @thebjorn Ok, let me adjust it a bit, working on the code right now

Comment: @tpullemku also - if you're dealing with "uniqueness" and an associated value - you want to be looking at Python's builtin `dict` type.

Comment: @thebjorn but doesn't -  ' '.join(str(my_indexes)) - the only non-string characters (integers) that there are in the code, turn them into strings, is that not enough?

Comment: No. `str([1,2])` is `"[1, 2]"`.  What you need is `["1", "2"]` (i.e. the individual items converted to string). Try `[str(index) for index in my_indexes]`.

Comment: @thebjorn No luck :-(

Comment: Then I would suggest rewriting to an explicit for-loop so you can use the debugger or print out intermediate values: `for item in sentence_seq: print repr(item), type(item)`

Comment: `try: " ".join(sentence_seq) except TypeError: print(sentence_seq) raise`

Comment: @TemporalWolf Where do i put that, under what variable?

Comment: @thebjorn It says invalid syntax under repr(item)

Comment: I suppose Python 3 requires parenthesis for print.. `print(repr(item), type(item))`

Comment: @thebjorn check the second answer (not an answer)

Answer (score 2):

Can you wrap that `print(" ".join(sentence_seq))` as below and post the result:

```
try: 
    print(" ".join(sentence_seq)) 
except TypeError: 
    print("Broken sentence: " + repr(sentence_seq))
    raise
```

See the example on [repl.it](https://repl.it/FPve/0)

---

This is **not a fix** (but may be useful, like the above, for troubleshooting):

```
print(" ".join(filter(None, sentence_seq)))
```

will remove the `None`s, but won't fix why they are `None` in the first place.

---

This is a **fix**:

```
my_indexes = ' '.join(str(uniquelist.index(word)) for word in error)
```

&

```
word_base = [z.strip() for z in f_base.read().split()]
```

You're adding 1 to the index, then adding a `None` to the start of the list... by removing both the issue no longer reproduces.

Comment: invalid syntax under 'except'

Comment: Are you sure you're copying it correctly? This works in both Python2.7 and Python3 for me

Comment: How can you post a bit of code in comments? sorry out of the topic lol

Comment: Edit your original question. You are the OP.

Comment: Do you mind writing your code part of your 'answer' again? Is there supposed to be such an indent for everything else except 'except'? Can you show it the way you are supposed to be shown? Don't be offensed, I'm not trying to be rude, it's just not clear and a bit confusing, as i said i'm not an expert in python, im a bit new

Comment: It should be exactly as it appears.

Comment: What do you get when you run the program? The syntax error has now gone, but now i get a list of some words in their own individual strings but most of them repeat and it only displays the first sentence. Also the first NoneType error comes at the end :-( I use python 3.5.2 btw if it makes any difference to python3

Comment: @tpullemku I posted a link to repl.it which has the example I showed. it's showing you what sentence_seq is when it crashes, which is probably not what you want it to be.

Comment: Yeah same thing of what i see, i guess there's nothing much to do about it, i might have to do it another way :-(((

Comment: @tpullemku I added a fix

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, this is for viewing ease only -
Bjorn this is the displayed result:

```
   'They' <class 'str'>
   'say' <class 'str'>
   'it' <class 'str'>
   "'" <class 'str'>
   's' <class 'str'>
   'a' <class 'str'>
   'dog' <class 'str'>
   "'" <class 'str'>
   's' <class 'str'>
   'life' <class 'str'>
   ',' <class 'str'>
   'They' <class 'str'>
   None <class 'NoneType'>
   'They' <class 'str'>
   'They' <class 'str'>
   'They' <class 'str'>
   'say' <class 'str'>
```

It outputs what is shown above, but what the purpose of the program is to print this :

```
   They say it's a dog's life, but for Estrella, born without her front legs, she's adapted to more of a kangaroo way of living. The Peruvian mutt hasn't let her disability hold her back, gaining celebrity status in the small town of Tinga Maria.
```

Comment: You should edit your original post to include this information. Don't follow my bad example ;)

Comment: Indeed. but you did notice the `None <class 'NoneType'>` on line 13 (position 12 if you start counting at zero).  That is a bug.  There shouldn't be a `None` there (since None isn't a string. Figure out how the None got there and fix it.. :-)

Comment: I have no clue as to me everything has been converted to individual strings and there is nothing else to do about that part of  the problem in my eyes. Am i missing something?

Comment: The problem is, when you think the program works one way and Python is telling you it works in a different way, then you'll need to figure out how your thinking about the program is wrong. This is called... debugging ;-)  Debugging is basically divide+inspect+repeat.  Find the spot in your program where your variables with wrong values were created, and inspect the variables at that point (print them).  Continue doing this until you find the problem.

Comment: `sentence_seq` gets its value from this line: `sentence_seq = [word_base[int(i)] for i in f_select.read().split()]`.  Maybe you need to print out `word_base`?  .. and also `f_select.read().split()`..